# Is this error because of the different in Python version?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to compare two list and then erase the common word in the second list. It works perfectly when I test this code online (version 3.6.1), but when I try with my python (version 3.7.3), it doesn't erase those words anymore

```
answer1 = "Ngôi sao cô đơn"
answer2 = "Bọ sát thủ"
answer3 = "Bọ chân đều khổng lồ"  

#xóa dấu
answer1 = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9ạẠảẢãÃàÀáÁâÂậẬầẦấẤẩẨẫẪăĂắẮằẰặẶẳẲẵẴóÓòÒọỌõÕỏỎôÔộỘổỔỗỖồỒốỐơƠờỜớỚợỢởỞỡỠéÉèÈẻẺẹẸẽẼêÊếẾềỀệỆểỂễỄúÚùÙụỤủỦũŨưƯựỰữỮửỬừỪứỨíÍìÌịỊỉỈĩĨýÝỳỲỷỶỵYỹỸđĐ'+"'"+' ]+', '', answer1)
answer2 = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9ạẠảẢãÃàÀáÁâÂậẬầẦấẤẩẨẫẪăĂắẮằẰặẶẳẲẵẴóÓòÒọỌõÕỏỎôÔộỘổỔỗỖồỒốỐơƠờỜớỚợỢởỞỡỠéÉèÈẻẺẹẸẽẼêÊếẾềỀệỆểỂễỄúÚùÙụỤủỦũŨưƯựỰữỮửỬừỪứỨíÍìÌịỊỉỈĩĨýÝỳỲỷỶỵYỹỸđĐ'+"'"+' ]+', '', answer2)
answer3 = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9ạẠảẢãÃàÀáÁâÂậẬầẦấẤẩẨẫẪăĂắẮằẰặẶẳẲẵẴóÓòÒọỌõÕỏỎôÔộỘổỔỗỖồỒốỐơƠờỜớỚợỢởỞỡỠéÉèÈẻẺẹẸẽẼêÊếẾềỀệỆểỂễỄúÚùÙụỤủỦũŨưƯựỰữỮửỬừỪứỨíÍìÌịỊỉỈĩĨýÝỳỲỷỶỵYỹỸđĐ'+"'"+' ]+', '', answer3)

print("AAAAAAA")
print(answer1)

#check 2 list câu hỏi và đáp án để xóa cái chung
sim_ques = "Loại bọ khiến người bị cắn dị ứng với thịt đỏ?" 
lowerQues = sim_ques.lower().split()
answersplit1 = answer1.lower().split()
answersplit2 = answer2.lower().split()
answersplit3 = answer3.lower().split()
print("BBBBBBB")
print(answersplit1)

if len(answersplit1) > 1:
        answer1 = [i for i in answersplit1 if i not in lowerQues]
        answer1 = [i for i in answersplit1 if i not in abbandonWords]
        print(lowerQues)
        print("ANSWER 1")
        print(answer1)
if len(answersplit2) > 1:
        answer2 = [i for i in answersplit2 if i not in lowerQues]
        answer2 = [i for i in answersplit2 if i not in abbandonWords]
        print(lowerQues)
        print("ANSWER 2")
        print(answer2)
if len(answersplit3) > 1:
        answer3 = [i for i in answersplit3 if i not in lowerQues]
        answer3 = [i for i in answersplit3 if i not in abbandonWords]
        print(lowerQues)
        print("ANSWER 3")
        print(answer3)
```

Wrong Output:

```
['ngôi', 'sao', 'cô', 'đơn']
['bọ', 'sát', 'thủ']
['bọ', 'chân', 'đều', 'khổng', 'lồ']
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work anymore."? What happens when you run it?

Comment: it doesn't erase the common words anymore @ParitoshSingh

Comment: What is output do you get then? The same as the original string? Because it is working for me on 3.7.3

Comment: are you sure the code you've written here and the code you are running are the same? because there's nothing in this code that should behave differently between python 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: Could you let us know the expected output? I'm confused about what you want to achieve

Comment: yes, I'm sure, I just copy and paste. The output I want is
['car']
['fire', 'fire']
['earth', 'earth', 'fire'] as I wrote

Comment: Can you show what you got on python 3.7.3? I couldn't reproduce the problem on my end

Comment: Ran your code [here](https://repl.it/languages/python3), got the same results.

Comment: Hello I've made an edit, they are actutally Vietnamese words. Could that be the problem? I want to remove the 'bọ' word

Comment: In just copypasted your code into a python 3.7.3 notebook and I get this output: `['ngôi', 'sao', 'cô', 'đơn']
['sát', 'thủ']
['chân', 'đều', 'khổng', 'lồ']`

Comment: let's first establish the fact that python version isn't the issue here. I am not sure what the issue would be though, i cannot reproduce this. can you tell a bit more about how you run this program in your machine? are you running this on the command line as a script?

Comment: Thank you, then it's not about the different in version, that's so weird hm......

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I posted full code, please take a look for me.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I figured it out, when I remove the line answer1 = [i for i in answersplit1 if i not in abbandonWords], answer2 = [i for i in answersplit2 if i not in abbandonWords]... it works. What can I do to keep that line?

Comment: @JessicaDương you overwrote whatever came in answer1 and answer2 by doing that. Perhaps use `answer1 =  [i for i in answer1 if i not in abbandonWords]` . Note that i am using `answer1` instead of using `answersplit1`. Having said that, you should really be looking into how to create a [mcve] .